# run xcode build command from a swift file

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7.3, ios9.3

I am using Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2

i use the below command to run my ios ui test.

```
xcodebuild test -project ios-ui-automation-demo.xcodeproj -scheme ios-ui-automation-demo -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air'
```

I use the below code to run my Xcode build command in swift.

```
import Foundation

func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [AnyObject]) -> String
{
let task = NSTask() //error here
task.launchPath = launchPath
task.arguments = arguments

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

return output
}


shell("xcodebuild", arguments: [ "test -project ios-ui-automation-demo.xcodeproj -scheme ios-ui-automation-demo -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air'"])
```

first of all this is showing error:

```
 Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTask' //how i can fix it in ios swift file
```

second is my code ok to run my command through swift?

Comment: You'e tagged this "iOS".  How sure are you that `NSTask` exists for iOS?

Comment: @Phillip Mills actually i am new to this area..... NSTask does not exist in ios but how i can do it alternatively

Comment: Since you want to launch "xcodebuild", shouldn't you be building/running this code as a Mac app?  When you say "how i can fix it in **ios** swift file", it seems like you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @PhillipMills actually i am doing  an ios app ui test. thats why i want to run it as ios file.

Comment: When you run your "xcodebuild" command interactively, you're running it on a Mac.  When you run it from code, it has to also be on a Mac.  If it causes something else to run on iOS, that's not really relevant.

Comment: @PhillipMills actually when i open my code in a different osx playground, that is ok but when i add this to my ios project, it shows error..... thats why i am asking for the solution of unresolved identifier 'NSTask' in ios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114365/discussion-between-shiblee-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: The final answer is: don't add it to an iOS project!  Whatever is making you think that you can execute "xcodebuild" (or other shell functions) from inside iOS code is wrong.